# Have echo and grep replace each time for-loop changes n

Tags: bash

my text file "testnum" looks like this:

```
xxx1abc
xxx2abc
xxx3abc
xxx4abc
xxx5abc
xxx6abc
xxx7abc
xxx8abc
xxx9abc
xxx10abc..etc
```

this gives my desired output in cmdline

```
for n in {1..10}
do
o=`sed -n "${n}p" < testnum`
clear
echo -e "you read ${o}\r"
grep  -n -C 2 ${o} testnum 
sleep 2s
done
```

and that looks like this which is what i want

```
you read xxx10abc
8-xxx8abc
9-xxx9abc
10:xxx10abc
11-xxx11abc
12-xxx12abc
```

just that it clears the cmd line everytime it iterates
what i want is this

```
nikola@nikola-desktop:~/Downloads$bash my_skirpt
you read xxx1abc
1:xxx1abc
2-xxx2abc
3-xxx3abc
```

last iteration should be

```
nikola@nikola-desktop:~/Downloads$bash my_skirpt
    you read xxx10abc
    8-xxx8abc
    9-xxx9abc
    10:xxx10abc
    11-xxx11abc
    12-xxx12abc
nikola@nikola-desktop:~/Downloads$
```

Comment: i want to have echo and grep replaced each time for-loop changes n, not a new output n changes

Comment: Sorry, still cannot figure it out.  You want to run `my_skirpt` multiple times and have *that* cause the `n` to advance?  So the first time you run the program it returns the first line, and the second time you run the program it returns the second line, etc?

Comment: I too am having problems understanding exactly what you mean.

Comment: I think I understood. You want the script not to clear the command line but "replace" the actual text on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain, but I think you want it to overwrite all the lines it printed the last iteration? In that case, you want to use `tput`:

```
#!/bin/bash
tput sc
for n in {1..10}
do
o=`sed -n "${n}p" < testnum.txt`
echo -e "you read ${o}\r"
grep  -n -C 2 ${o} testnum.txt
sleep 2s
tput rc
tput el1
done;
tput sc
```

`tput sc` saves the current cursor position, so we can later recall this position with `tput rc`. `tput el1` clears the line we're on so that the changing number of lines (first and last outputs are shorter than the other ones) doesn't destroy anything.

There is a lot more you can do with `tput`, google will for instance give you [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-learningtput/index.html) page, which I find quite good.